# Abstract class, Number, as my input in Java

Tags: java, numbers, instanceof

I was trying to figure out what to do with the abstract class Number in the context of implementing a method that inputs an entity in such form.

Below is a short java script i wrote that shows my confusion.

In the main method, I haven't been able to figure out how to make my input more generic so that when calling upon `whynowork` , it can print out a message according to its data type (Double,int,Comparable)

```
public class PleaseWork{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

  //where i was desperately trying to figure out how to input a number       
        int x= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        float a = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
        whynowork(3);

    }

// this tells you what data type your input is
    public static void whynowork(Number param) {

         if( param instanceof Double) {
            System.out.println("param is a Double");
        }
        else if( param instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("param is an Integer");
        }

        if( param instanceof Comparable) {
            System.out.println("param is comparable"); 
        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: Typically (at least for how I've used it), `Number` is best used for accepting any numerical input and using it for your desired numerical output. For example if you had an RGB method, you could accept `Number` for the red param, and get `red.intValue()` for your 0-255 int.

Comment: what's the use of the variables, when you are hardcoding a int literal

Comment: @Ramanlfc i was only temporarily harcoding a int literal because i wanted to make sure that my method was working fine (it was only there to test `whynowork`)

Comment: Do you receive an exception? What is the result and how is it different from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it to : `System.out.println("patam is a "+param.getClass().getSimpleName());`

Comment: apparently it doesnt work for float.  if i do the following `float a = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);` then `System.out.println("patam is a "+a.getClass().getSimpleName());`, i get an error message as follows `float cannot be dereferenced`

Comment: Also, If i understand it correctly, in Java, every first input in main is always gonna be a string.  I was hoping there is a way to have my code just figure out what data type my numerical input is (int double etc..)

Comment: It doesn't work for primitive types. I think you'd like to use `Float a = Float.parseFloat(args[0]); You return a Float value and then unbox it to primitive float.
Also as you can see every argument in main is a String because of `String[] args`.

Comment: I understand that in the argument of the main method, we are designating the type of our input as String but i think that's our only option. Any other data type designation will fail (isnt this true?)

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` or `public static void main(String... args)` - this is how Java Language is designed and Java Virtual Machine is designed and written. And String is used to be compatible with command-line arguments.

Comment: @stratofortress why it fails for `float` is because you are trying to call `.getClass()` for it, `float` being a primitive type (unlike `Float` which is a Wrapper class and extends `Number` abstract class) doesn't contain the `.getClass()` method. Although if you were to pass `a` in `whynotwork()` it would have worked fine because of _autoboxing_.